# How to get Date extra from an intent?

Tags: java, android, date, android-intent

I am packing an intent and one of the Extras I add is a date object, like this:

```
intent.putExtra(DATE_EXTRA, t.getDate());
```

Later, when I reading the extras, I try to get the Date like this:

```
this.date = new Date(intent.getExtras().getString(DATE_EXTRA));
```

However, this returns an error about the String being empty. I don't think the above is the right way to do it, because I am not looking for a string, but I have not been able to find an `intent.getDateExtra()` method anywhere. What do I do?

I know that the date was passed properly, because I can see it while debugging:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace:

```
this.date = new Date(intent.getExtras().getString(DATE_EXTRA));
```

with:

```
this.date = (Date)intent.getSerializableExtra(DATE_EXTRA);
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Strange though that you are allowed to put a Date extra but not call `getDateExtra` when I can call getString, getDouble, getLong, etc...

Comment: @McAdam331: "You are a godsend" -- you have a rather unusual god in mind. :-) "when I can call getString, getDouble, getLong, etc" -- `double` and `long` are primitives, and `String` is more popular than `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to pass the long value of the date:

```
intent.putExtra(DATE_EXTRA, t.getDate().getTime());
....
this.date = new Date(intent.getLongExtra(DATE_EXTRA, 0)); //0 is the default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Safe way in kotlin:

```
  intent.putExtra("MOVE_DATE", date)
```

and to read it in safe way by check for key & null check:

```
 val moveDate: Date?     
 intent?.apply {
 if (hasExtra("MOVE_DATE")) {
       moveDate = getSerializableExtra("MOVE_DATE") as? Date
       moveDate?.let { print(it) }
    }
 }
```